# Nginx 400 bad request and nothing interesting in logs

Tags: nginx, docker

I can't stop getting 400 bad request. After some research, I found out that this meant that the request had bad headers due to a bad configuration

Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1000;
}

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_tokens off;

    set_real_ip_from  192.168.0.0/16;
    set_real_ip_from  172.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent $http_host "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

Here is the output to logs when I do a get request to the server:

```
" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 172.26.0.5, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2021/09/16 11:08:07 [error] 8#8: *8 broken header: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-dest: image
referer: https://localhost/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
host: localhost
X-Forwarded-For: 172.26.0.1
```

This nginx reverse proxy is running on a docker container with the following `dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx:1.16

ENV DOCKER_IMAGE nginx
ENV DOCKER_NAME nginx
ENV TZ Africa/Tunis

RUN set -x && \
    # tiny helper to reload nginx config
    printf '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload\n' >> /usr/local/bin/nginx-reload && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/nginx-reload && \
    # delete nginx default server config
    rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY ./conf/ /etc/

ENV WORKER_PROCESSES auto
ENV WORKER_CONNECTIONS 1024

ENV SERVER_NAME localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

The `nginx.conf` has no configuration what to do with the requests, do you have any other configs e.g. in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` or in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

You can use the `server` block with the `location` block to configure a proxy or you can use the `root` directive to set it to an directory to send files out of it.

So to help you better do specify what do you want to make with nginx.